# How can I filter objects from a Django model that are (ManyToMany) related to a specific set of objects in another model?

Tags: django, django-models

I’ve got a Django model (`ModelA`) with a `ManyToManyField` linking to another model (`ModelB`).

I’d like to write a query that selects all instances of Model A that are related to a *specific set* of instances from Model B.

I’d kind of like to do it like this:

```
related_set = ModelB.objects.filter(id__in=(1,2))
ModelA.objects.filter(modelb_set=related_set)
```

But that seems to select Model A instances that are related to instances 1 *or* 2 in Model B.

I want to select Model A instances that:

1. are related to Model B instances 1 *and* 2;
2. are not related to any other Model B instances.

Answer (score 1):

After [some help from DrTyrsa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8385649/20578), I think I’ve got it:

```
model_b_1 = ModelB.objects.get(id=1)
model_b_2 = ModelB.objects.get(id=2)
model_b_other = ModelB.objects.exclude(id__in(1, 2))

# Select Model A instances that are related to Model B instances 1 AND 2:
related_to_1_and_2 = ModelA.objects.filter(modelb=model_b_1).filter(modelb=model_b_2)

# Then exclude Model A instances that are related to any other Model B instances
ONLY_related_to_1_and_2 = related_to_1_and_2.exclude(modelb__in=model_b_other)
```

Comment: Yes, stupid mistake. :-) If you want to add several conditions you can use `reduce` with `filter` method, or with [Q objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects). I just thougn using dict will be the most elegant, but no luck. :-) I've deleted my answer.

Comment: Sure — this would be much more useful generally if it could take an arbitrary number of conditions. Many thanks for your help though, it really pointed me in the right direction.